# Laravel doctrine only returning single attribute from findAll() query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Im using laravel doctrine in a lumen application, in one of my controllers i have an index function that should return all records from a given entity.

the function looks like this

```
public function index(ServerRequestInterface $request)
{
    return $this->showResponse(app()->make('em')->getRepository('App\Entities\showOff')->findAll());
}
```

which returns data like this

```
[
    {
      "nodeType": 'showOff'
    },
    {
      "nodeType": 'showOff'
    },
    {
      "nodeType": 'showOff'
    },
    {
      "nodeType": 'showOff'
    }
]
```

This is only one attribute in the entity.

If i turn the doctrine debugger on is see the executed SQL query like

```
SELECT t0.type AS type_1, t0.size AS size_2, t0.last_modified AS last_modified_3, t0.hair_cutter AS hair_cutter_4, t0.file_path AS file_path_5, t0.content_url AS content_url_6, t0.embed_url AS embed_url_7, t0.height AS height_8, t0.width AS width_9, t0.player_type AS player_type_10, t0.about AS about_11, t0.award AS award_12, t0.comment AS comment_13, t0.comment_count AS comment_count_14, t0.text AS text_15, t0.thumbnail AS thumbnail_16, t0.version AS version_17, t0.name AS name_18, t0.id AS id_19, t0.nid AS nid_20, t0.node_type AS node_type_21, t0.owner_id AS owner_id_22, t23.enabled AS enabled_24, t23.username AS username_25, t23.email AS email_26, t23.password AS password_27, t23.remember_token AS remember_token_28, t23.name AS name_29, t23.id AS id_30, t23.nid AS nid_31, t23.node_type AS node_type_32, t0.aggregate_rating_id AS aggregate_rating_id_33, t34.rating_count AS rating_count_35, t34.rating_score AS rating_score_36, t34.name AS name_37, t34.id AS id_38, t34.nid AS nid_39, t34.node_type AS node_type_40, t0.author_id AS author_id_41, t42.enabled AS enabled_43, t42.username AS username_44, t42.email AS email_45, t42.password AS password_46, t42.remember_token AS remember_token_47, t42.name AS name_48, t42.id AS id_49, t42.nid AS nid_50, t42.node_type AS node_type_51, t0.translator_id AS translator_id_52, t53.enabled AS enabled_54, t53.username AS username_55, t53.email AS email_56, t53.password AS password_57, t53.remember_token AS remember_token_58, t53.name AS name_59, t53.id AS id_60, t53.nid AS nid_61, t53.node_type AS node_type_62 FROM show_off t0 LEFT JOIN users t23 ON t0.owner_id = t23.id LEFT JOIN aggregate_rating t34 ON t0.aggregate_rating_id = t34.id LEFT JOIN users t42 ON t0.author_id = t42.id LEFT JOIN users t53 ON t0.translator_id = t53.id ;
```

when ran from the mysql command line it returns all data as it should.

Some where along the line all my attributes are being stripped out.

my entity looks like so

```
<?php

namespace App\Entities;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Jobs\IndexNewEntitiesJob;
use App\Jobs\UpdateIndexEntitiesJob;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use ApiArchitect\Compass\Entities\User;

/**
 * Class ShowOff
 *
 * @package Jkirkby91\DoctrineSchemas
 * @author James Kirkby <jkirkby91@gmail.com>
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifeCycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Table(name="show_off")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repositories\ShowOffRepository")
 */
class ShowOff extends \App\Entities\MediaObject
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    protected $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $size;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", length=45, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    protected $lastModified;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\ApiArchitect\Compass\Entities\User", fetch="EAGER", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $owner;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\App\Entities\HairCutter", fetch="EAGER", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\Column(nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    protected $hairCutter;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $filePath;


    /**
     * HairCutter constructor.
     * @param    $fileName   
     * @param    $filePath   
     * @param    $owner   
     * @param    $hairCutter   
     */
    public function __construct($fileName, $filePath, User $owner, $type, $lastModified, $size)
    {
        $this->name = $fileName;
        $this->filePath = $filePath;
        $this->owner = $owner;
        $this->type = $type;
        $this->lastModified = $lastModified;
        $this->size = $size;
        $this->nodeType = 'showOff';
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of filePath.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFilePath()
    {
        return $this->filePath;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of filePath.
     *
     * @param mixed $filePath the file path
     *
     * @return self
     */
    protected function setFilePath($filePath)
    {
        $this->filePath = $filePath;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of owner.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getOwner()
    {
        return $this->owner;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of owner.
     *
     * @param mixed $owner the owner
     *
     * @return self
     */
    protected function setOwner(User $owner)
    {
        $this->owner = $owner;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of hairCutter.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getHairCutter()
    {
        return $this->hairCutter;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of hairCutter.
     *
     * @param mixed $hairCutter the hair cutter
     *
     * @return self
     */
    protected function setHairCutter($hairCutter)
    {
        $this->hairCutter = $hairCutter;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

my config looks like so

```
<?php
return [

    'managers'                  => [
        'default' => [
            'dev'        => env('APP_DEBUG'),
            'meta'       => env('DOCTRINE_METADATA', 'annotations'),
            'connection' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlite'),
            'namespaces' => [
                'app'
            ],
            'paths'      => [
                env('COMPASS_ENTITIES',base_path('vendor/apiarchitect/compass/src/Entities')),
                env('AUTH_ENTITIES',base_path('vendor/apiarchitect/auth/src/Entities')),
                env('LOG_ENTITIES',base_path('vendor/apiarchitect/log/src/Entities')),
                env('NODE_ENTITIES',base_path('vendor/jkirkby91/lumendoctrinecomponent/src/Entities')),
                env('APP_ENTITIES',base_path('/app/Entities')),
            ],
            'repository' => Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::class,
            'proxies'    => [
                'namespace'     => false,
                'path'          => storage_path('proxies'),
                'auto_generate' => env('DOCTRINE_PROXY_AUTOGENERATE', false)
            ],

            'events'     => [
                'listeners'   => [],
                'subscribers' => []
            ],
            'filters'    => [],

            'mapping_types'              => [
                'enum' => 'string'
            ]
        ]
    ],

    'extensions'                => [
        LaravelDoctrine\Extensions\Timestamps\TimestampableExtension::class,
        LaravelDoctrine\Extensions\SoftDeletes\SoftDeleteableExtension::class,
        LaravelDoctrine\Extensions\Loggable\LoggableExtension::class,
        LaravelDoctrine\Extensions\Blameable\BlameableExtension::class,
        LaravelDoctrine\Extensions\IpTraceable\IpTraceableExtension::class,
        LaravelDoctrine\ORM\Extensions\TablePrefix\TablePrefixExtension::class,

    'custom_types'              => [
        'json' => LaravelDoctrine\ORM\Types\Json::class
    ],

    'custom_datetime_functions' => [],

    'custom_numeric_functions'  => [],

    'custom_string_functions'   => [],

    'logger'                    => env('DOCTRINE_LOGGER', trrue),

    'cache'                      => [
        'default'                => env('DOCTRINE_CACHE', 'memcached'),
        'namespace'              => null,
        'second_level'           => false,
    ],

    'gedmo'                     => [
        'all_mappings' => false
    ],

    'doctrine_presence_verifier' => true,
];
```

Does any one know why this is doing this?

Comment: I actually don't expect it to make a difference, but you did `->getRepository('App\Entities\showOff')` does anything change when you do `->getRepository('App\Entities\ShowOff')` (capital `S`).

Comment: What happens inside your `showResponse` method? What does `app()->make('em')->getRepository('App\Entities\showOff')->findAll()` return?

Answer (score 0):

You write in your question:

> Some where along the line all my attributes are being stripped out.

I suspect something happens with the data inside the `showResponse` method that you wrap around the result set that is returned from the repository `findAll()` call.

Try once to separate the result from the `showResponse` call and check what you get then:

```
public function index(ServerRequestInterface $request)
{
    $result = app()->make('em')->getRepository('App\Entities\ShowOff')->findAll();
    var_dump( $result ); // <-- should contain a collection of ShowOff entities.
    return $this->showResponse($result); // <-- something happens and returns an array
}
```